# Java ActionListener action not performed

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener, defaulttablemodel

I have a JButton which should remove the selected row from a JTable in my GUI. However, for some reason, the code in the `ActionListener()` that I'm using to do this never seems to get called...

```
private void addListeners(){
    ...
    //removeBtn = new JButton("Remove");
    removeBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("Remove button clicked. Printed from actionListener. ");
            removeRow(e);
        }
    });
```

The `removeRow()` method is defined later in the same class:

```
public void removeRow(ActionEvent arg0){
    System.out.println("'Remove' button pressed, Printed from 'removeRow()' method. ");
    int selectedRow = jEntityFilterTable.getSelectedRow();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jEntityFilterTable.getModel();
    model.removeRow(selectedRow);
    System.out.println("Selected row should have been removed. Printed from 'removeRow()' method. ");
```

`removeBtn` is declared as a global variable at the top of the class using the line:

```
private JButton removeBtn = new JButton("Remove");
```

When I run the code, and click the 'Remove' button on the GUI, nothing happens, and I don't even see the debug displayed in the console... but I can't work out why- can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? Why is the actionListener/ removeRow() method not being called?

**Edit 07/07/2014 @ 13:20**

Here is the full code for the relevant parts of the class, as requested:

```
public class JConfigurationPane extends JPanel implements UndoableEditListener, ChangeListener, ActionListener
{
    ...
    private JButton addBtn = null;
    private JButton saveBtn = null;
    private JButton removeBtn = new JButton("Remove"); //null;
    private JButton editBtn = null;
    public boolean addBtnClicked = false;
    public boolean saveBtnClicked = false;
    public boolean removeBtnClicked = false;
    public boolean editBtnClicked = false;
    /**
     * This method initializes 
     * 
     */
    public JConfigurationPane(ConfigurationDataModel dataModel)
    {
    super();

    this.dataModel = dataModel;

    initialize();
    initialiseData();
    addListeners();
}

public JConfigurationPane()
{
    super();

    initialize();

    addListeners();
}

private void addListeners()
{
    System.out.println("--- 'addListeners()' method has been called. ---");
    jcbRxFilterExcludes.addChangeListener(this);

    docRxAddress = jfRxAddress.getDocument();
    docRxPort = jfRxPort.getDocument();
    docRxExerciseID = jfRxExerciseID.getDocument();
    docRxMaxPduSize = jfRxMaxPduSize.getDocument();

    docRxAddress.addUndoableEditListener(this);
    docRxPort.addUndoableEditListener(this);
    docRxExerciseID.addUndoableEditListener(this);
    docRxMaxPduSize.addUndoableEditListener(this);

    addBtn.addActionListener(this);
    /*Add action listeners for other buttons (07/07/2014 @ 08:35) 
    saveBtn.addActionListener(this);
    removeBtn.addActionListener(this);
    editBtn.addActionListener(this);

    Causes an "Exception in thread 'main', java.lang.nullPointerException on: 
        'saveBtn.addActionListener(this);
        'addListeners();' call in 'public JConfigurationPane()'
        'JConfigurationPane panel = new JConfigurationPane()' call in 'main(String[] args)'
    */
    //removeBtn = new JButton("Remove");
    removeBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("Remove button clicked. Printed from actionListener. ");
            removeRow(e);
        /*  System.out.println("'Remove' button pressed. ");
            int selectedRow = jEntityFilterTable.getSelectedRow();
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jEntityFilterTable.getModel();
            model.removeRow(selectedRow);
            System.out.println("Selected row should have been removed. "); */
        }
    });
}

private void initialiseData()
{
    ...
}

/**
 * This method initializes this
 * 
 */
private void initialize() {
    ...

    /*Create filter buttons */
    System.out.println("------------------JButtons BEING CREATED---------------------");
    addBtn = new JButton("Add");
    addBtn.setBounds(950, 135, 125, 25);
   //     addBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
//      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

//      }
//  });
    JButton saveBtn = new JButton("Save");
    saveBtn.setBounds(1100, 135, 125, 25);
    JButton removeBtn = new JButton("Remove");
    removeBtn.setBounds(950, 200, 125, 25);
    JButton editBtn = new JButton("Edit");
    editBtn.setBounds(1100, 200, 125, 25);
    System.out.println("------------------JButtons CREATED-------------------------");

    ...

    /*Add filter buttons */
    System.out.println("-------------------JButtons BEING ADDED TO GUI--------------------");
    this.add(addBtn);
    this.add(saveBtn);
    this.add(removeBtn);
    this.add(editBtn);
    System.out.println("------------------JButtons ADDED TO GUI---------------------");
}

/**
 * This method initializes jfRxAddress  
 *  
 * @return javax.swing.JTextField   
 */
private JTextField getJfRxAddress()
{
    ...
}

/**
 * This method initializes jfRxPort 
 *  
 * @return javax.swing.JTextField   
 */
private JTextField getJfRxPort()
{
    ...
}

/**
 * This method initializes jfRxExerciseID   
 *  
 * @return javax.swing.JTextField   
 */
private JTextField getJfRxExerciseID()
{
    ...
}

/**
 * This method initializes jEntityFilterPane    
 *  
 * @return javax.swing.JScrollPane  
 */
private JScrollPane getJEntityFilterPane()
{
    ...
}

/**
 * This method initializes jEntityFilterTable   
 *  
 * @return javax.swing.JTable   
 */
private JTable getJEntityFilterTable()
{
    ...
}

/**
 * This method initializes jEntitySymbolsPane   
 *  
 * @return javax.swing.JScrollPane  
 */
private JScrollPane getJEntitySymbolsPane()
{
    ...
}

/**
 * This method initializes jEntitySymbolsTable  
 *  
 * @return javax.swing.JTable   
 */
private JTable getJEntitySymbolsTable()
{
    ...
}

/*Method to add buttons to 'Plugin Configuration' window */
private void addButtons(){
    /*Buttons moved up to initialize() method on 25/06/2014 @ 17:00 */
    JButton addBtn = new JButton("Add");
    JButton saveBtn = new JButton("Save");
    JButton removeBtn = new JButton("Remove");
    JButton editBtn = new JButton("Edit");

    addBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            /*(25/06/2014 @ 15:20) Need to add code here to add a new editable row to 'Entity Filter' table */
            addBtnClicked = true;
        }
    });
    //addBtn.setBounds(1150, 135, 30, 15);
    saveBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            /*(25/06/2014 @ 15:20) Need to add code here to save the data in the 'Entity Filter' table to a set of variables */
            saveBtnClicked = true;
        }
    });
    //saveBtn.setBounds(1190, 135, 30, 15);
    removeBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        /*(25/05/2014 @ 15:25) Need to add code here to remove the data in selected row from variables, and remove row from table */
            removeBtnClicked = true;
        }
    });
    //removeBtn.setBounds(1150, 160, 30, 15);
    editBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            /*(25/06/2014 @ 15:25) Need to add code here to enable editing of data in selected row */
            editBtnClicked = true;
        }
    });
    //editBtn.setBounds(1190, 160, 30, 15);
    System.out.println("'addButtons()' method is being called by 'initialize()' in JConfigurationPanel.java");
}

/**
 * This method initializes jcbRxFilterExcludes  
 *  
 * @return javax.swing.JCheckBox    
 */
private JCheckBox getJcbRxFilterExcludes()
{
    ...
}

/**
 * This method initializes jfRxMaxPduSize   
 *  
 * @return javax.swing.JTextField   
 */
private JTextField getJfRxMaxPduSize()
{
    ...
}

@Override
public void undoableEditHappened(UndoableEditEvent editEvent)
{
    ...
}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changeEvent)
{
    ...
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));

    JConfigurationPane panel = new JConfigurationPane();

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    /*Check which button has been pressed, perform a different action depending on which button it was. Reset the check variables
     * to false after performing action */

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    /*Code to add row to table when button is pressed */
    System.out.println("'Add' button pressed.");

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jEntityFilterTable.getModel();

    Object[] obj = new Object[]{}; 

    System.out.println("Row Count: " + model.getRowCount());
    System.out.println("1st Column: " + model.getColumnName(0));
    System.out.println("Column Count: " + model.getColumnCount());

    model.addRow(obj);

    System.out.println("--- ActionListener added to 'addBtn' ---");

    /*Code to remove selected row from the table when button is clicked 
    int selectedRow = jEntityFilterTable.getSelectedRow();
    model.removeRow(selectedRow); */

}

public void removeRow(ActionEvent arg0){
    System.out.println("'Remove' button pressed. Printed from 'removeRow()' method. ");
    int selectedRow = jEntityFilterTable.getSelectedRow();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jEntityFilterTable.getModel();
    model.removeRow(selectedRow);
    System.out.println("Selected row should have been removed. Printed from 'removeRow()' method. ");
}
}
```

Comment: Not enough code. You should provide a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . But my bet is that with `removeBtn = new JButton("Remove");` you are creating a *new* button that is different from the one that you see on the screen (which may have been created somewhere else...)

Comment: Make sure that you don't mistakenly replace the JButton somewhere, so you end up with a button that doesn't have the ActionListener attached.

Comment: I had previously declared `removeBtn` as a global variable with `private JButton removeBtn = null;`. Given your comment however, I tried changing the global declaration to `private JButton removeBtn = new JButton("Remove");`, and then removing the line `removeBtn = new JButton("Remove");` from the code in the `addListeners()` method, however I still have the same trouble with nothing happening when I click the 'Remove' button on the GUI...

Comment: Stupid question: Do you actually call `addListeners()` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes, I call `addListeners()` in the constructor.

Comment: It will be much better if you post your whole code here. And let us know.

Comment: The class is quite large, so I'll cut out everything else, and just post the relevant parts now.

Answer (score 1):

In your `initialize()` method, the `removeBtn` you are adding to the panel is a local variable to that method.  The same thing occurs in the `addButtons()` method.  Then, later, when you call `addListeners()`, you're adding the `ActionListener` to the private member `JButton` which was not added to the panel.  Remove the local `JButton removeBtn` from the `initialize()` method and initialize the member one instead.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, and for pointing out those issues. I've done what you suggested- got rid of all of the 'new' private JButtons that I've created, and used the member one instead. However, when I now run my code, once all of the initialisation code has run (and I get the "... being created... " messages and "addListeners() method has been called" message in the console), I then get an "Exception in thread main" with a null pointer exception again.This time it's occurring on the line `dataModel.setEntityFilterExcludes(jcbRxFilterExcludes.isSelected());` in the `stateChanged()` method

Comment: Well, good, your original issue is solved, but if you're looking for advice on your new problem, you'll need to post the conetnt of the stateChanged() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare button as final field. If some part of your code change your button object, you will get a warning.

Comment: I know you can't comment yet, but this should really rather be a comment... good idea, though.

Comment: I gave this a go, but it didn't make any difference at all to what's happening when I run the code...

Answer (score 0):

> with a null pointer exception again.

In your code you use:

```
JConfigurationPane panel = new JConfigurationPane();
```

instead of:

```
public JConfigurationPane(ConfigurationDataModel dataModel)
```

Why do you have two constructurs? Why would you ever pass in the data model to the class?

Also, don't use setBounds() to set the size/location of your buttons. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers, so use layout managers. Maybe you would start with a panel that uses a `FlowLayout`.

Finally, the following code (probably) won't work:

```
model.removeRow(selectedRow);
```

The selected row refers to the row in the view of the table, not the row in the table model. If you code does sorting or filtering, then the index may be different. You first need to convert the selected index using:

```
JTable.convertRowIndexToModel(...);
```